# Laravel Jobs and Queues not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I'm creating an application which generates a video. This is a quite intensive function and takes a few minutes to generate. So I want to create a async process for this. After some research I've read about Jobs and Queues in Laravel.

But now my jobs don't get inserted in the `jobs` table. I can't find out what I've done wrong.

**My function which starts the job:**

```
public function generate() {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    GenerateJob::dispatch($id);
}
```

**My Job**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use Auth;

class GenerateJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct($dossierId)
    {
        $this->dossierId = $dossierId;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

**.ENV** `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`

I did run `php artisan clear:config` but nothing seems to help.

Nothing I try seems to work. The `jobs` table remains empty and the job is executed synchronously instead of asynchronously. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging I finally found a solution to my problem. Adding `->onConnection('database');` to `GenerateJob::dispatch($dossier_id);` solved it all..

I wish I could say why this was necessary, but I have no clue since I already put that in my .env file. Hope this helps for someone else in this situation. :-)